# I want to initialize function variable as the one that was previously inputted

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I input:

`router = router("a",graph)`

in my main function. This will take the graph and put it into this router function. I want my find function, i want the start to be the "a" that I assigned there above etc, but I tried self.name etc but its not working. How do i fix it?

```
class router(object):
    def __init__(self,name,Graph):
        self.name = name
        self.Graph = Graph

def find(self, start=name, maxD=1e309):
```

Comment: The `a` is saved as `self.name` and you can access it that way in the `find` method. You claim you tried that, it would be helpful to see that attempt and see if we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you can't initialize parameters based on other parameters, so you can initialize it to `None` then check if it's `None`:

```py
class router(object):
    def __init__(self,name,Graph):
        self.name = name
        self.Graph = Graph

    def find(self, start=None, maxD=1e309):
        if start is None:
            start = self.name
        # start is now initialized to self.name
        pass
```

Comment: hi when i do this   def shortestpath(graph,start=None,end):
        """Find the shortest path btw start & end nodes in a graph"""
        # detect if first time through, set current distance to zero
        
        if start is None:
            start = self.name
        pass
it returns  non-default argument follows default argument

Comment: If you give `start` a default value, you must also give `end` a default value, since it comes after `start` in the argument list

Comment: but i in my function find("f") i want to pass f into end while having graph and start already there, do i still have to assign a default value? sorry i am quite new to this

Comment: Then you should give a default argument for graph and make end the first argument and pass them as keyword arguments.

Comment: sorry what do you mean by keyword arguments like in defining the function? Thanks alot for your help .

Comment: You should read up on [default arguments](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-arguments-in-python/) and [keyword arguments](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_function_keyword_arguments.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `functools.partial` method to pre-initialize a name-mangled `_find` method and store it to `find`:

```
from functools import partial

class router(object):
    def __init__(self, name, Graph):
        self.name = name
        self.Graph = Graph
        self.find = partial(self._find, start=name)

    def _find(self, start, maxD=1e309):
        print(start, maxD)


rtr = router('router_name', 'some_graph')
rtr.find()
# Out: router_name inf
rtr.find(start='new_start', maxD=np.pi)
# Out: new_start 3.141592653589793
```

Since this involves overwriting the **keyword** argument `start`, it is imho best practice to force the `_find` method to accept only keyword arguments with the `*`-syntax:

```
    def _find(self, *, start, maxD=1e309):
        print(start, maxD)
```

See the [`functools.partial` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) for more information. The sentence

> If additional keyword arguments are supplied, they extend and **override** keywords.

is the important part considering your question.